# How to know when real time update ends - Cloud Firestore ionic 4 with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I'm using cloud firestore for my DB, having no problems with read and writes. My issue is that i don't understand how to know when real time update has ended!
I'm using real time update as described in official cloud firestore documentation. It returns a function instead an observable. Now i'm not sure how to use it correctly.
I need to execute some code after data is loaded, but i have no subscribe((data) => {...}) to put it there!!
How to do it?
If i show lack of knowledge, please guide me to some documentation.
Thanks

This code is working fine and i'm using it directly on html like ListService.places$ to access data array.

```
public places$: BehaviorSubject<Array<Place>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<Place>>([]);
private unsubscribe: Function;

public list(city: string, country: string) {
      return this.unsubscribe = this.firestore.firestore.collection('places')
          .where("location.country", "==", country)
          .where("location.city", "==", city)
          .orderBy("startDate", "desc")
          .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
              const list: Place[] = [];

              if(!querySnapshot.docs.length) {
                  this.places$.next(list);
              } else {
                  querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                      let places = new Place();
                      place = doc.data() as Place;
                      places.push(place);
                      if(list.length === querySnapshot.docs.length) {
                          this.places$.next(list);
                      }
                  });
              }
          });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to `this.places$`

```
this.places$.subscribe((data) => {
   console.log(data);
});
```

What the real time function returns does not metter, because the real time function  adds the output to the `BehaviorSubject`.

See here

```
let places = new Place();
place = doc.data() as Place;
places.push(place);
if(list.length === querySnapshot.docs.length) {
   this.places$.next(list);
}
```

That means if you want to do something with the data you just need to subscribe to `places$`.

Also i think you have a small typo there, you never pushed values to the `list` array.
It should be something like:

```js
...
.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
   const list: Place[] = [];

   if(!querySnapshot.docs.length) {
      this.places$.next(list);
   } else {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
         let place = new Place();
         place = doc.data() as Place;
         list.push(place);
         if(list.length === querySnapshot.docs.length) {
            this.places$.next(list);
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: That's it Norbert. Now i understand what i was missing! Could not be more simple. Everything was right, but i was using SubjectBeahviour the wrong way, causing confusion in my mind.
Thanks a lot